# How can I remove magic strings from custom model binders?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, magic-string

I've written a couple of custom model binders now, and have realised that I've fallen into the trap of relying on magic strings, e.g.:

```
    if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix("PaymentKey"))
    {
        paymentKey = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("PaymentKey").AttemptedValue;
    }
```

I'd like to be able to use an expression to strongly-type the prefix names, but can't figure out how, and would be grateful for some assistance.

Thanks.

Comment: You could create a static class to hold those string values as properties and reference the properties instead. For example: bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix(SomeClass.PaymentKey)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `bindingContext.ModelName` so your code could become:

```
 if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix(bindingContext.ModelName))
    {
        paymentKey = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).AttemptedValue;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but no, this isn't what I'm looking for.  Maybe my question could have been clearer, but I was looking for a way to avoid using magic strings for each property, not the model as a whole.  Thanks anyway.